# Displaying page list and a custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to display a list of child pages under $parent_id. This is done in a page template inside the loop. You will see that Im trying to also get a advanced custom field value which in this case is a image url. I have everything working except the image url, Currently i'm getting the value "80" in the image source. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$parent_id = $posts[0]->ID;
$args=array(
  'post_parent' => $parent_id,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo 'List of Posts';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'story_detail_story_image', true ) ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'story_detail_story_image', true ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php   endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Comment: you have set return value on your image field to image ID. [the documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) shows examples for fetching images for the different return values available to the image field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see there, I'd expect that your problem is the meta value in story_detail_story_image is storing an image id.

Try replacing the following

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'story_detail_story_image', true ) ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'story_detail_story_image', true ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With the following

```
<?php
$image_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'story_detail_story_image', true );
if ( ! is_int( $image_id ) ) {
    echo "<p>Image ID not an integer. It is:</p><pre>"; var_dump( $image_id ); echo "</pre>";
} else if ( $image_id ) {

    # The next line tries to grab an image with that id in thumbnail size
    $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );
    if ( ! is_array( $image_data ) ) {
        echo "<p>Image data not an array! It is:</p><pre>"; var_dump( $image_data ); echo "</pre>";
    } else if ( is_array( $image_data ) ) {
        # The next line grabs the url, which is stored in the first element of the array
        $image_url = $image_data[0];

        # the next three lines just grab post information
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_title = esc_attr( get_the_title() );
        $post_link = get_permalink();

        # The following displays the link. I just prefer heredoc syntax but you should be able to change it back if wanted
        echo <<<HTML
<a href="{$post_link}" rel="bookmark">
    <img class="thumb" src="{$image_url}" alt="{$post_title}" />
</a>
HTML;

    }
}
?>
```

That should grab the image id, use it to get the url, and then draw your link.

(revised to output what is wrong).

Comment: i modified the echo "<li><a href=".$post_link."><img src=".$image_url."></a></li>";  but this now doesnt return anything.

Comment: Adjusted to echo the value of variables that are not what they are expected to be so that _something_ should be output to diagnose.

Comment: Result: Image data not an array! It is:

boolean false

Comment: Should be fixed now. The 3rd parameter to get_post_meta is to tell if it is a single entry or not ... I was thinking of get_option's extra parameter to specify a default.